# how to get paginate to work with public/index.html? (ruby on rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, will-paginate, pagination

I asked this question 3 days ago but it went unanswered.
Here's the link for additional info: [how to get paginate to work instead of getting redirected to 'public/index.html'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16307019/how-to-get-paginate-to-work-instead-of-getting-redirected-to-public-index-html?rq=1).

I will clarify/simplify the question here.

I am using public/index.html as my visitor homepage. After a user logs in, the new homepage is at '/home'. On this '/home', there is a feed. I paginate the feed using this in my view `<%= will_paginate @posts %>`.

The problem as you might imagine is that, when I try to click on the 2nd page from paginate, the link is `http://www.mydomain.com/?page=2`. This redirects back to public/index.html. How can I get paginate to work properly?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Why not delete `public/index.html.erb`? That's a static page and you can't have dynamic elements on it like pagination.

The root request for your application should be being dealt with by a root route:

```
root :to => "home#index"
```

Then the pagination logic in `app/views/home/index.html.erb`.

Comment: `public/index.html` is for anonymous visitors. I have `static_pages/home.html.erb` which is for logged in users. I'm trying to get pagination to work for `home.html.erb`... how can I delete `public/index.html` and make this work correctly?